# Why is the verb not in last or second position?

Tags: word-order

This sentence appeared in a recent episode of Rote Rosen.

> Bis wir offen sind für Neues.

I would have thought that one of the following would have been more correct.

> Bis wir sind offen für Neues.

or

> Bis wir offen für Neues sind.

Any comments to explain the word order?

Comment: *[Bis] [wir] **sind** offen für Neues* is not a possible sentence: in a hypothetical main clause, there must be exactly one and only one element before the finite verb ('V2 word order'). However, *bis* couldn't be that element since it is a subordinating conjunction that always introduces a subclause. Your second example (*bis wir offen für Neues sind*), however, is perfectly fine as a subclause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule, that the finite verb always stands at position 2 (and all other verbs at the end) applies only for full statements. It is not valid for:

- questions

  > **Schläfst** du?
- commands

  > **Geh** mir aus den Augen!
- jokes

  > **Kommt** eine Frau zum Arzt und sagt ...
- ellipses and fragments of sentences

  > **Macht** elf neunzig.
- subordinate clauses (which are fragments of full sentences)

  > ..., weil ich ein Mädchen **bin.**

Your examples is a fragment; it is a subordinate clause. A full sentence containing your example might be:

> Alle **warten,** bis wir offen sind für Neues.

The word *»bis«* is a very complicated word that appears in many different situations. Here, in this sentence, it behaves like a subordinating conjunction. And German subordinate clauses normally have their finite verb at their last position:

> Ich bleibe noch ein wenig, ***weil** ich den Sonnenuntergang sehen **will.***
> Ich bleibe, ***bis** ich den Sonnenuntergang **sehe.***
> Alle warten, ***bis** wir für Neues offen **sind.***

The field, that is occupied by finite verbs in subordinate clauses is called *»rechte Klammer«,* and normally this really is the last field in a sentence. But there is also a *»Nachfeld«* behind this *»rechte Klammer«,* but in most sentences it is left empty. But it can be used as a place to position parts of speech that you want to point out, so that they get more attention, and this is done in this version:

> Alle warten, *bis wir offen sind **für Neues.***